# What should ASCII character 26 do?

Tags: character-encoding, ascii, ansi

I have code where I display ANSI art, I've found that last 128 bytes hold [SAUCE](http://www.acid.org/info/sauce/sauce.htm) meta data.

The problem I have is just before the SAUCE data there is one character that looks out of place,

[image]

that is ANSI code 26, [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) show this as (substitute).

What should this character do? Should it cause anything after it to be ignored?

Here is [a demo of my JavaScript Terminal](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/pxdxmN?editors=1010) that displays ANSI art (working commands are `ls` and `cat`).

Some of the listed ANSI files have this character at the end (not all of them have SAUCE data).

Comment: Ctrl-Z is an end-of-file indicator in DOS and Windows. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42333492/505649)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character 26 is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, [the substitute character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) in ASCII, which is commonly used as [the end-of-file marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) in CP/M, DOS, and descendants. (CP/M doesn’t store exact file sizes in bytes, only in 128-byte blocks, so an explicit EOF marker is useful there; DOS did store exact file sizes so it doesn’t need EOF markers.)

Many tools developed for those operating systems will stop processing files when they encounter this character. So on a typical 80×25 DOS screen, with `ANSI.SYS` or equivalent,

```
TYPE yourfile.ans
```

would output the file to the screen, relying on `ANSI.SYS` to interpret the ANSI escapes, and stopping at the end-of-file marker, so [the SAUCE records don’t appear on-screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475529/86440).

Comment: End-of-file as far as some of the housekeeping utilities (e.g. the `type` command) are concerned, but [this is a common fiction overlaid by application libraries over the top of an operating system API _where it was not_ EOF](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/dos-character-26-is-not-special.html).  When I wrote a `type` command for my own command interpreter, [this was one of the CP/M Think things that I did not replicate](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/cmd.html).  Ironically for a question that does not mention Unix or Linux, MS-DOS was more Unix-like in this regard than it is often given credit for.  (-:

Comment: Indeed @JdeBP, thanks for the clarification.